# is candoerz.com associate with serverfault in any way?

Tags: discussion

I was going though my google postback links and found these (2) links...

http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/113042/apache2-serveralias-not-working.aspx

[Apache2 - ServerAlias not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/734665/apache2-serveralias-not-working)

Is candoerz.com associated with serverfault (I really doubt it)?

Comment: No, that site is just a badly behaved scraper and should be treated as such.